# Is this an objective or subjective claim "With enough experience, a person who doesn’t like opera can come to appreciate it"?

Tags: critical-thinking

My reasoning is that the veracity of the claim depends on what a person considers "enough experience" and thus makes it a subjective claim. But on the other hand, if there were a way to measure "enough experience" (for example average time taken by a human to appreciate opera), then it will be objective. What makes me doubt is that for example the claim "Portland, Oregon, is closer to the North Pole than to the Equator" is considered objective but it is assumed that the specific strategy for measuring proximity is already established independently of the person.

Comment: What's the keyword in re *(objective) claims*? That should at the very least get the party started. *Que sais-je?*

Comment: You seem to be conflating subjectivity with imprecision.

Comment: Some persons will never like opera. Some other persons will start by disliking it, then will come to appreciate it due to some experience. Some person will be rather neutral to it, then will come to hate it due to some experience. There is nothing particularly subjective about these observations. Your claim refers to "enough experience" and "a person", which are both vague enough to make sure the claim is not false.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you consider the sentence: 'A scientific study has confirmed that some people who now claim to like opera also admit that they did not like it when they first heard it'. Would you say that was objective? In what important ways does it differ from the claim in your headline question?

Answer (score 0):

It is a subjective claim because it makes the presumption that the correlation of enough experience with Opera by the person who does not like it will **cause** the said person to like it *unless* the presumption is factual, whereby if the presumption is factual, then the claim is objective.

Answer (score 0):

I would expect that someone who made this claim meant by "enough" "Enough to achieve the result that the person likes it." Which would make it unfalsifiable or circular. So as it stands, the claim is empty. The other major problem with the claim as you have formulated it is that you would need the co-operation of the person who does not like opera; if they close their ears and refuse to listen, nothing will happen.

However, there is a real point underlying it, which is that the music we hear affects what music we like. We can only like or dislike music that we have heard, so that shouldn't be surprising. (Actually, there are all sorts of other factors that affect what music we like, such as various features of the artist or its social or political context, and so forth. But that's not the focus here.)

Less obvious is the point that music of a kind we have not heard, or not heard much, or not listened to carefully, is often not appealing to us. However, this is not always the case. Sometimes music that is new to us appeals to us straight off; sometimes we need time to get used to it before we can enjoy it.

It's worth remembering that like and dislikes in music can be occur at different levels. So a genre, such as classical or jazz can be liked or disliked, sometimes a style, or a composer or performer.

You seem to want to classify the claim as objective or subjective. But this claim is not as simple as that. There are objective and subjective elements to it. The element of liking or disliking is, of course, subjective in that someone's reports of their likes or dislikes is authoritative (normally). How much opera and which operas the person has heard/seen and what effect it has had on them is objective; however, what reaction they have to it is subjective.